# Doing AJAX when browser's window is closed

Tags: javascript, socket.io, chat, laravel-echo

I have a chat app which utilizes Laravel Echo with Pusher (which is similar to Socket.io).

And the issue I'm getting here is I can't update a user online status in database if there's no single user is online on the other side

Been searching on internet and found out about `unload` event in Javascript, but they told that it's not reliable to handle this problem.

I also have yet to find an event on the Laravel Echo to trigger it even though Pusher records it with "Disconnection" event every time a user load the page or browser is closed

What is the most effective way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about used tools. Maybe use fake user/bot to keep at least someone online always?

Regarding closing window. There are other events suitable for this. The most obvious and recommended would be `beforeunload`. Another option is `pagehide`, but it's less supported for now and has a bit different meaning.

Also `navigator.sendBeacon()` might be useful here as network request transport. That way browser doesn't have to wait for response.

Comment: just tested `beforeunload` and it's still not effective for AJAX requests

Comment: Normal AJAX requires response, `sendBeacon()` doesn't. I'm using it for similar task, but I don't need 100% reliability though.